# Mange HTTP response in android

Tags: android, http, android-2.3-gingerbread

i am firing a HTTP post request post request from a AsyncTask in android to the server.

the problem i am facing in managing the response. here how i read the response.

```
HttpEntity entity =response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) {

    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream( entity.getContent());
    String str;
    while (( str = in.readLine()) != null){


    Log.e("Debug","Server Response second url"+str); 

 }
   in.close();
}
```

the issue is i am getting the response in pieces , but i wanted them in a one piece

*Current Response*

```
 Server Response second url
 Server Response second url<header><status>Success</status><message>Check the Numbers:
 Server Response second url123456.</message><vbal>5005</vbal></header>
```

*Expected Response*

```
<header><status>Success</status><message>Check the Numbers:123456.</message><vbal>5005</vbal></header>
```

if i will get it in a one piece i can parse the xml response easily and fetch the required value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(str);
}
in.close();
str = sb.toString(); //here you have the string you need.
Log.e("Debug","Server Response second url" + str);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have Apache commons:

```
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8");

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(in, writer);

String str = writer.toString();
```

Otherwise,

```
final char[] buffer = new char[0x10000];
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
Reader in = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "UTF-8");

try {
    int read;

    do {
        read = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        if (read > 0)
            out.append(buffer, 0, read);
    } while (read >= 0);
} finally {
  in.close();
}

String str = out.toString();
```